# How can I cut a collection of images in half on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, batch, image-processing

I have 50 images. I need to cut each image in half (vertical cut). How can I do that on Windows 10 via a batch process (= not cutting each image manually one by one)? All the images are in a single folder.

E.g., the image

[image]

is cut into the following 2 images:

[image]  [image]

Sometimes all the images have the same dimensions or aspect ratio, sometimes not. I'm ok with any image processing software running on Windows.

Comment: Do all images have the same resolution and also the same aspect ratio? [Edit] your question to add some more Information and tools you are using for image-processing.

Comment: @help-info.de thanks, edited!

Answer (score 8):

As far as I know, there is no image splitting application native to Windows, however, there is a very well known free utility called Imagemagick, available for Linux, Mac OS X, iOS, and Windows.

You can download the installers here (scroll up/down to see the other OS releases)

https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows

Choose an appropriate 32-bit or 64-bit binary. I have 64 bit Windows 10, and i chose

ImageMagick-7.1.0-51-Q16-HDRI-x64-dll.exe

Run the installer, and make sure to check the box to install legacy utilities.

[image]

Once the installer has completed, you will have a folder in your Windows 'Program Files' folder called something like

`C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.1.0-Q16-HDRI`

In this folder will be a command-line executable called 'convert.exe'.

Do not confuse this with the Windows program called convert.exe which is in C:\Windows\system32\ and which converts a FAT volume to NTFS.

Now you can make a batch script in the folder where you have your 50 image files, something like this

```
@echo off
for %%A in (*.jpg) do (
    "C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.1.0-Q16-HDRI\convert.exe" -crop 50%%x100%% "%%~nxA" "%%~nA-split%%~xA" 
)
```

**You will need to change the file extension specified if it is not `.jpg`**

**Update the file path in the program to match the actual file path on your computer.**

This is what I got. The left split is the split-0.jpg file and the right split is the split-1.jpg file.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For image processing [IrfanView](https://www.irfanview.com/) is installed under Windows by many users. As an alternative solution to ImageMagick there is a ***Save image tiles*** dialog for one (or a few) files. Batch processing is also possible via settings in the GUI.

Please note and you are warned - keep your originals (save copy) in case it goes wrong.

### Use case for multiple files in folder

Having multiple images of different dimensions a few steps are required.

From the main menu follow these steps:

- *File > Open* and open one image
- *File > Thumbnails* (or use shortcut `T`). This will open IrfanView Thumbnails.
- Sort images by dimensions in Thumbnails view
- *Options > Sort thumbnails > by Image width*

[image]

- Select all files having same image width (e.g. 2048px).
- File > Start batch dialog With selected files... (or use shortcut `B`). Please note the selected files are now listed in `Input files`.
- Select *Batch conversion - Rename result files* under `Work As`
- Click **Batch conversion setting** <kbd>Advanced</kbd> to crop x-offset: `0` and width e.g. `1024` px and `Left top`for the first pass like shown in the screenshot. Use `Save settings`for your needs.
- Open **Batch rename settings**. Set name pattern `$N_1`.
- Browse for output folder or use current folder.
- Click *Start batch*

[image]

- Use the <kbd>Return to batch</kbd> button.
- Again open **Batch rename settings** and set name pattern `$N_2`
- Again Click **Batch conversion setting** <kbd>Advanced</kbd> to crop x-offset: `0` and width e.g. `1024` px and `Right top`for the second pass.

Select other images with different dimensions and repeat the steps above.

### Use case for single file (maybe few files) only

From the main menu use:

- File > Open
- Options > Export image tiles (split image) ...
- Set Number of tiles (columns and rows) for your needs e.g. 2 x 1

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be a batch? If it can be a Powershell script, then;

- save this as SomeName.ps1
- right click on it
- pick "Run with PowerShell".

It'll create empty folder where you can place images if you dont create one(i assumed jpg images), also you can pick what direction you want to cut them(no third party :) );

```
param (
    [string]$cutDirection = ""
)

if (-not $cutDirection) {
    $cutDirection = Read-Host "Enter '(h)orizontal' or '(v)ertical' to specify the cut direction.`nPress Enter for default (horizontal)"
}

if ($cutDirection -notin @("horizontal", "h", "vertical", "v")) {
    Write-Host "Invalid cut direction. Defaulting to 'horizontal'."
    $cutDirection = "horizontal"
}

Write-Host "Getting the current directory..."
$currentDir = $PSScriptRoot
Write-Host "Current directory: $currentDir"

$imagesFolder = Join-Path -Path $currentDir -ChildPath "Images"

if (-not (Test-Path -Path $imagesFolder -PathType Container)) {
    Write-Host "Images folder not found. Exiting..."
    Exit
}

Write-Host "Changing to the Images folder..."
Set-Location -Path $imagesFolder
Write-Host "Current directory: $PWD"

$outputFolder = Join-Path -Path $currentDir -ChildPath "CutImages"
if (-not (Test-Path -Path $outputFolder -PathType Container)) {
    Write-Host "Creating output folder for cut images..."
    New-Item -Path $outputFolder -ItemType Directory | Out-Null
    Write-Host "Output folder created: $outputFolder"
}

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

Write-Host "Collecting list of JPG files..."
$jpgFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $currentDir -Filter *.jpg -Recurse
if ($jpgFiles.Count -eq 0) {
    Write-Host "No JPG files found in the parent folder."
    Exit
}

Write-Host "Processing JPG files..."
foreach ($file in $jpgFiles) {
    Write-Host "Processing: $($file.FullName)"
    $image = $null
    try {
        $image = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile($file.FullName)
    } catch {
        Write-Host "Error loading image: $($_.Exception.Message)"
        continue
    }

    if ($image -eq $null) {
        Write-Host "Failed to load image $($file.FullName). Skipping..."
        continue
    }

    $width = $image.Width
    $height = $image.Height
    Write-Host "Image dimensions: Width = $width, Height = $height"

    if ($cutDirection -eq "horizontal" -or $cutDirection -eq "h") {
        Write-Host "Cutting $($file.Name) horizontally..."
        $newWidth = [math]::Round($width / 2)
        $newImageA = $image.Clone([System.Drawing.Rectangle]::FromLTRB(0, 0, $newWidth, $height), $image.PixelFormat)
        $newImageA.Save("$outputFolder\$($file.BaseName)_a.jpg")
        $newImageB = $image.Clone([System.Drawing.Rectangle]::FromLTRB($newWidth, 0, $width, $height), $image.PixelFormat)
        $newImageB.Save("$outputFolder\$($file.BaseName)_b.jpg")
        Write-Host "$($file.Name) cut horizontally."
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "Cutting $($file.Name) vertically..."
        $newHeight = [math]::Round($height / 2)
        $newImageA = $image.Clone([System.Drawing.Rectangle]::FromLTRB(0, 0, $width, $newHeight), $image.PixelFormat)
        $newImageA.Save("$outputFolder\$($file.BaseName)_a.jpg")
        $newImageB = $image.Clone([System.Drawing.Rectangle]::FromLTRB(0, $newHeight, $width, $height), $image.PixelFormat)
        $newImageB.Save("$outputFolder\$($file.BaseName)_b.jpg")
        Write-Host "$($file.Name) cut vertically."
    }
    $image.Dispose()
}

Write-Host "Image processing complete."
```